# Blender viewport no anti aliasing

Tags: antialiasing

I have been trying to get the viewport to look smooth but my PC refuses to apply any anti aliasing. 
Because of this, I have great difficulty working on my models.

Here is what it looks like,
[image: 1]

[image: 2]
Here are my settings

What can I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this true also for the "default" scene? I mean, a simpe cube...do you see jagged edges also there?

Comment: AA doesn't work with viewport ambient occlusion, make sure you have AO disabled

Comment: Ambient occlusion is off and I get the same result with the default scene.

Answer (score 2):

[@Osian Sodenkamp](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/32409/osian-sodenkamp)'s tip worked in my case. You have to disable screen-space ambient occlusion in the display options panel (hidden under `N` key). I'd never find it out if it weren't for Osian's comment!

[image: Blender ambient occlusion]